# ZeroClipBoard : Multiple clipboard in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am trying to add zero clipboard in tabs, where each tab box contains its own clipboard. Its working fine when I put the text fields and buttons outside tab boxes, but didnt work when I put them in tabs.

Please check the link below what I have done so far.

**NOTE:** (the flash movie clip isnt appearing in jsfiddle, but its appearinh and repositioning in my local copy)

[Link for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EUvLj/1/)